# Converting the comma separated string

Tags: c#, java, regex, string

I have a string which is in following format or comma separated format

`s1 ,s2,s3,s4,`and so on. I want to convert it into

```
s1
s2
s3
s4
..
..
..
```

I know  how I can do this by using a loop but I want to do this by regex in c# and in java without using the loop can I achive this ???

Comment: Thousands of question abouts this. Did you do a little of research before asking? string.Split no regex needed for this.

Comment: This is a very basic question, google for simple regex explanation.

Comment: Convert the string and print in the console? Or store it in some list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it in Java.

```
public class MainProg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "s1,s2,s3,s4";
        String z = s.replaceAll(",", "\n");
        System.out.println(z);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

find : `\s*,\s*`

replace with : `\n`

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, myString.Split(','));
```